# SCSS: Calculating with a value with unit from function

Tags: sass

I am defining values for a theme via a map, like this:

```
$sizes: (
    small: 768,
    medium: 1024,
    large: 1200,
    xlarge: 1600,
    gutter: 48
);
```

and afterwards give them a unit with the following function:

```
@function sz($size) {
    @return map-get($sizes, $size) + px;
}
```

How can I define a variable by calculating with one of the values out of the function, e.g.

```
$gutterhalf: (sz(gutter) / 2);
```

So the variable would return 48px / 2 = 24px? I know I could just go with the unitless value and add the unit afterwards, like so:

```
$gutterhalf: (map-get($sizes, gutter) / 2) + px;
```

Would there be a way to handle it differently with the value from the function?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/69f282fbbb7beb70d79fd5ed9b15f05a) to do live sass demos but I can't seem to share my sass demo without it automatically switching to dart-sass. Very weird.

But I've made a fiddle outputting results to a before pseudo content style on divs by id.

See experimental ideas in fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/0mbsc2g3/

And here is scss code below...

```scss
// array with no pixel unit, just integers
$sizes_0: (
    sm: 768,
    md: 1024,
    lg: 1200,
    xl: 1600,
    gutter: 48
);


// both functions below use array above

// this function allows you pass diving data through
@function sz_0($size, $divide: 1) {
    @return map-get($sizes_0, $size) / $divide + px;
}

// this outputs 24px
$gutterhalf_0: sz_0(gutter, 2);


// this function simply returns the array value
@function sz_2($size) {
    @return map-get($sizes_0, $size);
}

// this outputs 24px
$gutterhalf_2: ( sz_2(gutter) / 2 ) + px;


// array with pixel unit
$sizes_1: (
    sm: 768px,
    md: 1024px,
    lg: 1200px,
    xl: 1600px,
    gutter: 48px
);


// this function simply returns the array value with unit
@function sz_1($size) {
    @return map-get($sizes_1, $size);
}

// this outputs 24px
$gutterhalf_1: sz_1(gutter) / 2;


// sass results in content

#sz_0::before {
    content: '#{$gutterhalf_0}';
}

#sz_1::before {
    content: '#{$gutterhalf_1}';
}

#sz_2::before {
    content: '#{$gutterhalf_2}';
}
```

Comment: Thanks already. I must be doing something wrong. If I do it exactly as I describe above, first the map, then the function, then I define `$gutter_half: sz(gutter) / 2;`, when I use the variable $gutter_half, the output value is '48px/2', not '24px'. I see you're using another $divide variable - direct division with a value with a unit doesn't work?

Comment: I'll put some comments in SCSS to explain better.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/heqg3rxc/1/ - it outputs the same as my initial example. I just wanted to know if I can use a value with a unit from a map and divide it with SCSS, without extra variables/divider markup - it just doesn't seem to work this way?

Comment: Thanks again for your comments! From what you wrote, it seems I need to use the divider in order to get from a value with unit from a map to my final value I want (in this case, division by two = 24px, as displayed in $gutterhalf_0). I can either use a divider or only the plain numeric values to perform division on a value.

Comment: It because it's a string with px. There must be away to divide a pixel unit value in two.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/dzq840ao/2/ ok check this out if look at my comments marked `/* exactly the same */` they both return `48px`. If you then add `/ 2` to the end of both of them. My one comes out at `24px` and your one comes out at `48px/2`. Cant get my head around that.

Comment: You don't perform the division with `sz_3(gutter)` for $gutterhalf_3 (you just put out the full value, not the /2 one) - if you do that, you'll end up with 48px/2 as well I suppose :).